# C/C++ - run Makefile programmably

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have made a Makefile. To use it, I open my Terminal, go to the containing folder and run it with:

```
make flash
```

My question is, how can I do this in C/C++? That is, how can I invoke make inside my program (programmably)?

Answer (score 5):

The `system` function is your friend:

```
system("make -C /Users/MyNAME/Desktop/Folder flash");
```

Comment: Thanks thiton, but does the system function work in mac/xcode?

Comment: @user1104856: Consult your fine manual page, reachable by `man -s 3 system` from the Terminal.

Comment: should also change dir, to be shure to locally reference files

Comment: So: system("make -C /Users/MyNAME/Desktop/Folder flash"); work on mac/xcode?

Comment: it should work, because the: man -s 3 system ' tells me :D thanks!

Comment: But thiton, what if the makefile is in the same folder?

Comment: HOW DO YOU KNOW IF IT DONE OR FAILS ?

Comment: @user1104856: 1. Writing in all-upper caps is somewhat rude. 2. Read the manpage of `system`, then ask questions.

Comment: Hehe, sorry if i sound rude, forgive me.. i'm new to mac and the keyboard is ..wird

Comment: My friend, i used system("make -C Makefile flash"); becouse the makefile is in the same folder, but don't work, please help me out

Comment: @user1104856, you should give us more information than "doesn't work". What happens? Is there an error message?

Comment: Beta i'm using :  system("make -C /Users/MyNAME/Desktop/Folder flash");, but how do i change the /Users/MyNAME/Desktop/Folder  to point to the same folder ?

Comment: I'm trying to read i file called: Makefile it works if i do:

system("make -C /Users/MyNAME/Desktop/Folder flash");, but i want the path to point on the same folder were the exe file is running which is the debug folder.
locally reference files

Comment: i'm getting make: *** No rule to make target `flash'.  Stop.
if i do: system("make flash");

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `system` function, like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

system("make flash");
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, you are running it with " make flash ", but you did'nt tell the program its name+